# Expected Result is <0> Instead of a Date

Tags: java, date, junit, junit4

I have this Junit test that I am trying to write for a date. The piece of code the unit test is for is a function that returns a date. Below I have what I wrote for the code.

```
    public void getLatestHistoricalLossDate() {

    List<Overview> scenarioListTest3 = new ArrayList<Overview>();

    String name = "third_scenario-test";
    ISO8601DateFormat df = new ISO8601DateFormat();
    Date estimationDate = null;
    try {
        estimationDate = df.parse("2017-01-28T22:25:51Z");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Date creationDate = null;
    try {
        creationDate = df.parse("2017-02-28T22:25:51Z");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Double balance = 131750000.0;
    Double individualReviewImpairment = 1000.00;
    Map<String, Double> baseline = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    baseline.put("complete", 1000.0);

    Map<String, Double> macroAdjustment = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    macroAdjustment.put("complete", 2000.0);

    Map<String, Double> qualitativeAdjustment = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    qualitativeAdjustment.put("complete", 3000.0);

    Date positionDate = null;
    try {
        positionDate = df.parse("2017-01-28T22:25:51Z");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Date lossHistoryDate = null;
    try {
        lossHistoryDate = df.parse("2017-01-28T22:25:51Z");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String status = "active";

    Map<String, Integer> period = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    period.put("Q1", 2017);

    boolean publish = true;

    Overview ac = new Overview(4, name, estimationDate, creationDate, balance, individualReviewImpairment, baseline,
            macroAdjustment, qualitativeAdjustment, positionDate, lossHistoryDate, status, period, publish);

    scenarioListTest3.add(ac);

    Mockito.when(scenarioDashboardService.getLatestHistoricalLossDate()).thenReturn(lossHistoryDate);
}

@Test
public void testgetLatestHistoricalLossDate() throws Exception {

    getLatestHistoricalLossDate();

    ISO8601DateFormat df = new ISO8601DateFormat();
    Date testLossHistoryDate = scenarioDashboardService.getLatestHistoricalLossDate();
    assertEquals(df.parse("2017-01-28T22:25:51Z"), testLossHistoryDate);
    int expectedHistoricalDate = testLossHistoryDate.compareTo(testLossHistoryDate);
    Date lossHistoricalDate = df.parse("2017-01-28T22:25:51Z");
    assertEquals(expectedHistoricalDate, lossHistoricalDate);
}
```

When I run the test, it states that the expected result is 0 instead of the date listed which I don't understand why. Normally I would have the `assertEquals()` statement as `assertEquals(1, testLossHistoryDate.size());` but the `.size` does not work with dates. Anyone know a different way to do the same thing?

Comment: `int expectedHistoricalDate = testLossHistoryDate.compareTo(testLossHistoryDate);` - I think that this line has a different semantic than you think it has. If you compare two objects in Java, you will will get a negative `int`/`0`/positive `int` iff. the instance you call `compareTo(...)` on is smaller than/equal to/larger than the argument.

Comment: So what should that be replaced with? I need to be able to check that there is only one date being given and not more or less (hence the `assertEquals` statement in the code).

Comment: `assertNotNull(testLossHistoryDate)`? That would mean there is exactly one date.

Comment: Without a better understanding of your requirements I don’t think we can tell. `assertEquals(expectedHistoricalDate, lossHistoricalDate);` requires a `Date` to be equal to an `Integer` (obtained by autoboxing an `int`). This is never going to happen. And `testLossHistoryDate.compareTo(testLossHistoryDate)` will always return 0 since you are comparing a `Date` to itself.

Comment: assertNotNull worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    assertNotNull(testLossHistoryDate);
```

This checks that there is exactly one date.

Since your methord’s return type is `Date`, it cannot return more than one `Date`. It can however return `null`, that is, no date at all; but the above assertion will catch if that happens and fail the test.

PS The `java.util.Date` is long outdated. You may do yourself the favour of looking into `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. **Link:** [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).